# Is there any statistic test in R that would be appropriate for low number of observations? (4)

Tags: r, statistics

I work in R. I have this table. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfta7.png)

I want to test the values within each category of chemical compounds for significant differences. (Only in each category separately)

Comment: Please edit the output ``dput(data)`` to share your data rather than posting images. Thank you.

Comment: To add to the previous commenter, to get the best answers, your question/problem should be reproducible. Read this post to learn more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Using the base R `apply` and `summary` functions should get you started.  If your datafame is named `df`:

```
sumstats <- apply(df, 2, summary)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
lapply(df, summary)
```